# Adding appcompat-v7 in gradle is not switching my layout views to AppCompat versions automatically

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-xml, android-appcompat

I need to have the same look in pre-lollipop buttons and post-lollipop buttons, and I'm modifying the button color with `colorButtonNormal` attribute.

I'm using this theme for my app: `<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">`

As I need same look in all android versions I'm doing this in gradle:

```
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
```

As it's mentioned in the documentation, just adding that line will transform all your widgets in your xml layouts into appcompat versions of those widgets, to show the same look in old android versions than in modern android versions.

AppCompat version of the `Button` must be capable of access this attribute in xml:

```
<Button
    app:backgroundTint="@color/unpressed2">
</Button>
```

But something is going wrong because its ignoring it. And if I forze that xml widget to be a AppCompat version, it works perfectly:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton
    app:backgroundTint="@color/unpressed2">
</android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton>
```

Why adding implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0' is not automatically changing all my `Button` widgets into `android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton` widgets?

Comment: Are you using a Material Theme or AppCompat theme?

Comment: @GabrieleMariotti I'm using <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">

Comment: @NullPointerException This will automatically be used when you use Button in your layouts and the top-level activity / dialog is provided by **appcompat**.

Comment: @NullPointerException is your activity extends AppCompatActivity?

Comment: @RahulKhurana thank you very much again! that was the problem.I didn't know that you need to use AppCompatActivity in order to use AppCompat widgets in xml layout. Please post it in an answer, I will accept it.

Comment: @NullPointerException I've posted an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `AppCompatActivity` in order to use `AppCompat widgets` in xml layout.